# Circe Decoding a List of objects

Tags: scala, decode, encoder, circe

I have defined  a `case class User(id : String, name : String)`
I have defined both json encoders and decoders as :

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.{deriveConfiguredCodec, deriveConfiguredDecoder, deriveConfiguredEncoder}

  implicit val userEncoder: Encoder[User] = deriveConfiguredEncoder

  implicit val userDecoder: Decoder[User] = deriveConfiguredDecoder
```

I need to also define the encoder/decoder for `val res: List[User]`

is there something built in circe besides using something explicit ?

Comment: Hi again :)  - You don't need to do anything at all. If a `Decoder[Foo]` is in scope, **circe** will generate a `Decoder[List[Foo]]` out of the box for you. PS: `Encoder` + `Decoder` = `Codec` check this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/cyBbcG1fS0GwA3ygVYKv9g/7

Comment: take a look at implicit function `io.circe.Decoder.decodeList` and `io.circe.Encoder.encodeList`, they are useful for implicit `Decoder/Encoder` of some type `A`